# How to do this loop in java

Tags: java, loops

I have **n** number of objects which have a property called status.
So I have to check this property on all the objects and come up with a single value for all of the objects.

Let me explain.

The status property can have values like this (Strings) - "1","2","3","4","5","7","completed","not completed",......(any string other than 1..7)

- I will go through all the objects and if the status property has the value of 1-7 for any of the objects, the higher one will be selected then that value will be selected.
  **example**

> obj1.status="1", obj2.status="6".  Value Selected="6"
>
> obj1.status="4", obj2.status="2".  Value Selected="4"
>
> obj1.status="7", obj2.status="6".  Value Selected="7"

- If none of the objects have status property as 1-7 , then value selected will be "XYZ"
  **example**

> obj1.status="completed", obj2.status="abc".  Value Selected="XYZ"
>
> obj1.status="abc", obj2.status="def".  Value Selected="XYZ"
>
> obj1.status="jkl", obj2.status="mno".  Value Selected="XYZ"

If atleast one of the objects has status property as 1-7 and all the rest have other strings then number value will be selected.

> obj1.status="abc", obj2.status="1".  Value Selected="1"
>
> obj1.status="abc", obj2.status="5",obj3.status="4",.  Value
>   Selected="5"

Comment: are they json object??

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Jai--- no. This is core java. Status is a property on these objects.

Comment: set the current result to 0, then iterate over the objects. If you find a numerical status greater than the current result, set the current result accordingly. If the current result equals 0, return XYZ, else return the current result.

Comment: @Turamarth- I am not able to find some good way to do it. Tried various loops but it's not giving me the required functionality.

Comment: What should be the result in there are no objects? I suppose "XYZ"

Comment: @robert. My use case makes sure that there is always atleast one object.

Comment: Can't we have a custom Comparator and then pick first element after sorting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be something like this:

```
String regex = "[1-7]";
int max = 0;
int number;

for (Object obj : objectList){
  if(obj.status().matches(regex)){
      number = Integer.valueOf(obj.status());
      if(number > max){
        max=number;
     }
  }
}
if(max==0){
  System.out.println("XYZ");} 
else{
  System.out.println(String.valueOf(max));
}
```

Comment: `int max = "XYZ"`??

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like that:

```
Optional<YourObject> optional = test.stream().
filter(object -> (object.status.matches("[1-7]"))).sorted((o1, o2) -> Integer.valueOf(o2.status).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(o1.status))).findFirst();
String value = optional.isPresent() ? optional.get().status : "XYZ";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    String newStatus = list.stream()
            .map(Obj::getStatus)
            .map(x -> {
                try {
                    return Integer.parseInt(x);
                } catch (NumberFormatException ignore) {
                    return null;
                }
            })
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .max(Comparator.naturalOrder())
            .map(x -> Integer.toString(x))
            .orElse("XYZ");

    list.forEach(x -> x.setStatus(newStatus));
```

`Obj` is type of your objects.

Answer (score 1):

That's a classic reduce algorithm. (No casts and regular expressions nessecary.)

```
BinaryOperator<String> reducer = (v1, v2) -> {
    if (v1.length() == 1 && v1.compareTo("1") >= 0 && v1.compareTo("7") <= 0) {
        // v1 is a number - return v2 if higher number, else v1
        return v2.length() == 1 && v2.compareTo("1") >= 0 && v2.compareTo("7") <= 0 && v1.compareTo(v2) < 0 ? v2 : v1;
    } else {
        // v1 is not a number - return v2 if number, else "XYZ" 
        return v2.length() == 1 && v2.compareTo("1") >= 0 && v2.compareTo("7") <= 0 ? v2 : "XYZ";
    }
};
```

Test:

```
Stream<String> of1 = Stream.of("3", "1", "2");
Stream<String> of2 = Stream.of("1", "incomplete", "2");
Stream<String> of3 = Stream.of("incomplete", "status");
System.out.println(of1.reduce(reducer).get()); // 3
System.out.println(of2.reduce(reducer).get()); // 2
System.out.println(of3.reduce(reducer).get()); // XYZ
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class LoopTest {

    private class Item {
        private String status = "";

        public Item(String status) {
            if(status != null)
                this.status = status;
        }

        public String getStatus() {
            return status;
        }       
    }

    private static final Pattern MY_REXP = Pattern.compile("[1-7]");
    private String getValue(List<Item> listValues) {
        if(listValues == null)
            return "XYZ";

        Optional<Item> opItem = listValues.stream().filter(item -> MY_REXP.matcher(item.getStatus()).matches()).max(new Comparator<Item>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Item o1, Item o2) {
                if(o1 == null || o2 == null)
                    return -1;
                return o1.getStatus().compareTo(o2.getStatus());
            }
        });
        return opItem.isPresent() ? opItem.get().getStatus() : "XYZ";
    }

    @Test
     public void test1() {
        try {
            List<Item> listValues = Arrays.asList(new Item("1"), new Item("6"));
            String result = getValue(listValues);
            Assert.assertTrue("6".equals(result));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Assert.fail("Exception " + ex);
        }
    }

    @Test
     public void test2() {
        try {
            List<Item> listValues = Arrays.asList(new Item("completed"), new Item("8"));
            String result = getValue(listValues);
            Assert.assertTrue("XYZ".equals(result));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
           Assert.fail("Exception " + ex);
       }
    }

    @Test
     public void test3() {
        try {
            List<Item> listValues = Arrays.asList(new Item("abc"), new Item("5"), new Item("4"));
            String result = getValue(listValues);
            Assert.assertTrue("5".equals(result));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
           Assert.fail("Exception " + ex);
       }
    }

}
```